# What would be needed in C++ so that we can always use references and never pointers?

Tags: c++

According to what I found on the net, you should use references as much as you can, except when you must use a pointer. As far as I understood, the only reasons to use a pointer are:

- when dealing with raw memory **or**
- when you may have to return null **or**
- when you are dealing with the returned newly allocated object from new().

The first cannot really be handled. It's intrinsic in the task.
The second can be handled by a Null object pattern, and return a reference to that Null object. It requires that you define a Null object per each class instance you want to be able to refer to as Null.
The third can be handled with a smart pointer.

What I am wondering is: is it possible to "go java in C++" and program completely using references disregarding pointers altogether ? Would it be possible to define, by language, a null object in C++ like in Java ?

Sorry if the question is badly stated or a FAQ, I am very rusty on C++ and I have to start a new project in it, so I need to re-learn a few new things and get used to think in a different way.

Comment: One more reason is interacting with legacy code

Comment: The second can be accomplished with `boost::optional`.

Comment: The point is that java acts more like always using pointers, but using the dot-notation while C++ uses the "->" notation (since the dot notation is used when you have references). I mean, in java you have a null reference and `==` compares addresses, while in C++ `==` does the same as `.equals()` in Java.

Comment: Neither pointers nor references are required in programs, although completely avoiding either is stupid.

Comment: Actually javas references behave more like c++ pointers then c++ references, since the can be null, can be reassigned and comparing them compares the addresses instead the objects. So the only thing missing is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I'd be radical and say "nothing is needed, C++ is already like that." You need pointers for memory handling and for I/O, but outside that you ought to be able to design a "pure" C++ program without explicit raw pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Really how would you do that? I find it quite difficult to program without using pointers or classes which basically do nothing more then encapsulate pointers (mostly smart pointers and vectors).

Comment: @Grizzly: If you have an actual example, post it as a question on Codereview and we can think about it (or join the chat). Don't be afraid of hearing things like "broken from the start" or "redesign", though -- my claim only applies to complete programs, not tips of icebergs.

Comment: @Grizzly: it depends what you mean by "not using pointers". If I write `std::shared_ptr<Foo> myfoo(new Foo);`, no pointer type appears in my code but of course there's a sub-expression with pointer type. If we take `operator->` out of `shared_ptr` and just use `operator*`, then we can use smart pointers without ever directly using the pointer, so other than creating them in the first place, we don't need to "use pointers" in order to use smart pointers. It's a matter of taste whether you consider this "not using raw pointers", but as Kerrek says you aren't explicitly using them.

Comment: The purpose of references in C++ is to support call by reference, return by reference and capture by reference. You almost never want to use them for anything else. Many programmers new to C++ think of C++ references as Java references or C# references, but they are not. A `T&` in C++ is like a `ref T` in C#, not like a class reference in C#. If you want something akin to C# references, use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T>`, depending on the desired ownership semantics.

Comment: You seem to be asking about pointers to objects but it is also worth mentioning function pointers and pointer to members. These pointers can lead to very simple solutions to certain problems (selection of behaviour). Cutting yourself off from this facet of the language will force you to write more convoluted code to achieve something can be done far more simply.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot reseat a Reference but you can reseat a Pointer to point to new variables, this behavior cannot be simulated anyway in references(References always remain bound to the variable they are initialized to) and the convenience which pointers provide in achieving this would practically make C++ without pointers and only references virtually impossible .

Comment: If you restrict yourself to data representations, yes. Nothing stops you from doing that with functions though.

Comment: @MSN: Can you elaborate on your comment,I am afraid I do not understand it.

Comment: If you don't persist references, i.e., bind them to data, you can "reseat" them by passing down a different reference to a function. I.e., reseating references is only an issue with long-lived data.

Comment: @MSN, what you are telling about is like functional programming, where you always have immutable objects, am I right?

Comment: @Lol4t0, It's similar, yes. The idea is that you derive the state you care about from your inputs rather than persist it.

Answer (score 7):

What would be needed? Rebindable references - aka pointers. References are, once bound, not able to change their referee.

```
struct Anchor{ /*some data*/ };

struct Sprite{
  void set_anchor(Anchor const& a){ _anchor = &a; }
  Anchor const* _anchor;
};

struct Entity{
  Anchror _anchor;
};
```

With something like this, you can just reposition a `Sprite` on the screen by changing its anchor. How would you do that with references?

Comment: oh... wow. I forgot that. You can't reassign references. Once bound, they stick to that object. Is this possible in C++0x ?

Comment: @Xeo: see Haskell for details ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Well... take a guess how that's implemented. :)

Comment: @Stefano: No, C++11 doesn't change anything w.r.t. to reference semantics AFAIK.

Comment: @Xeo: I'd guess "implementation-defined"! In other words, the hand doesn't care because the face is busy thinking about real C++ :-)

Comment: @Steve: Sorry, I don't get it. :(

Comment: @Xeo: Haskell is a pure functional language, it doesn't provide mutating operations such as this "assignment" and "rebinding" of which you speak. Or at least, "pure" code doesn't use any mutating tricks.

Comment: @Steve: Ah. Well, given that C++ is *not* purely functional, would you propose to make it such to entirely abandon pointers? :)

Comment: @Xeo: Well, it's one way to overcome your objection. I suspect not the best, since once you remove side-effects there isn't much of C++ left.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reseat a reference, and you can't have a null reference.  What Java calls references are actually pointers.  And I don't know why you would want to avoid them.  References (in C++) have a specific role: they allow using the same syntax as pass/return by value, without the overhead; they can also be used for inout parameters and for exposing the internals of an object (e.g. an `operator[]` will often return a reference).  Other than as function parameters or return values, they should be fairly rare.

Comment: In some sense, references are crucial to allow you to have *objects*. Imagine you want to say `T a; T b = a;`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't understand your comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @FredOverflow: You need to have a copy constructor for that construction to work naturally, and you can only define a copy constructor with references.

Comment: @KerrekSB C with classes had copy constructors but no references, so they aren't essential ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow Given the definition in the current standard, it wouldn't be a copy constructor if it didn't take a reference:-).  But there's no doubt that you don't need references to copy objects.  The reason references were introduced was for the syntax: you don't want to have to write `&a + &b`, in order to pass pointers to the overloaded `operator+`.  After that, giving them different semantics than pointers opened up additional uses for them.

Answer (score 1):

The Null Object Pattern is really bad, just so you know. It's not any sort of far-reaching solution.

Pointers are needed to be rebindable, and that's it. Also, Java's "references" are actually C++'s "pointers". C++'s "references" have no Java equivalent.

Comment: proof of why/when Null Object Pattern is really bad. I mean, not just 'unnecessary' (which is _simpleton_ - bad) but, "really bad"?

Answer (score -5):

I have reassigned C++ references in the past using code something like this:

```
struct EmptyType {};
const EmptyType Null;

template<typename DataT>
class DynamicReferenceT
{
    union
    {
        DataT & _ref;
        DataT * _ptr;
    };

public:
    DynamicReferenceT(DataT & r) : _ref(r) { }

    void operator=(DataT & r) { _ptr = &r; }
    void operator=(const EmptyType &) { _ptr = NULL; }
    DataT & operator()() { return _ref; }
};

class SomeClass
{
    int _value;

public:
    SomeClass(int val) : _value(val) {}
    int value() { return _value; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SomeClass objA1(100), objA2(200), objA3(300);

    // initially define the dynamic ref
    DynamicReferenceT<SomeClass> refObj(objA1);
    cout << "refObj = " << refObj().value() << endl;

    // reassign the dynamic ref
    refObj = objA2;
    cout << "refObj = " << refObj().value() << endl;

    refObj = objA3;
    cout << "refObj = " << refObj().value() << endl;

    // assign "null" to reference
    refObj = Null;

    return 0;
}

// output
100
200
300
```

You can't overload the `.` operator in C++, so I overload the `()` operator to "dereference" the dynamic reference.

This is just a toy example -- you should further flesh out the implementation to handle deletion of objects and copying.

**Update**
I concede to the C++ community here that this was a very poor C++ example on my part and really stands as a good example of how to abuse C++. I don't actually promote such constructs in practice save for the one case I mentioned where I had to redefine references in a very, very bad legacy C++ library I inherited some years ago (at a dot-com who shall remain nameless).

Comment: @Xaade Oh, I've seen far far worse. This code is merely an example of how you can reassign references if you need to...or just interested in pursuing the "can I make C++ like Java/C#" exercise.

Comment: well, it hurts, but it's quite clever... :)

Comment: I believe that storing a value in a union through one member and then retrieving through a different member results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @hypercode No, it's isn't bad, it's breaking a language barrier. Using this you can put anything into a reference to anything else, which breaks enforcing type checking. Sure you coated it in your own protective layer using a template, but you broke type system of the language to do so. Unions are mutually exclusive data space savers, not a clever way to cast around casting restrictions. What if the pointer is used to delete the object, and that data is later used to instantiate a structure. Now you have the first four bytes of the structure acting as a reference to a type DataT.

Comment: @Ferruccio while that may be true, are there any compilers where this wont work?

Comment: If this compiles, it's time to change compilers.  According to the
standard (§9.5/2) "If a union contains a non-static
data member of reference type the program is ill-formed."

Comment: Erm... why the hell do you even use a union? Why not just a plain pointer if you have that in your union anyways?

Comment: @josefx that doesn't matter at all. If it's undefined, then it may work on a compiler on one release, and then not at all on the next release. An update on a compiler to fix an issue, is free to remove support for the expected reflex. So a silent background update changes the meaning of your code. Hence, UB is a bad practice.

Comment: reassigning references **is using pointers**. This sucks big time

Comment: @Xaade as a blanket statement that is true. However the gcc docs state that this is common and guarantees that it will work(even setting the -strict-aliasing flag wont break it). In this case the silent background update you mention would piss of a lot of users.

Comment: oh damn. Didn't see the union. Burn it! Burn it from the orbit!